# Access JQuery Autocomplete List Item

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I want to access the `li.ui-menu-item` from `ui-autocomplete` class

But, it can't be accessed via this code:

```
$("body .ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item").addClass("active");
```

I'm trying to add a class. I know that this can be done thru `data`, `append` and `appendTo`, but my scenario's different.

Each list items has a link tag in ajax, meaning a `data-remote=true` link that pass a certain URL parameter.

Then using my backend PL, there's a condition that will check if the parameter is present, then it should mark a specific list item as active. That's why I wanna add a class named `active`

Comment: You want  to extend [_renderItem](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem)

Comment: Actually, it's weird if I can't access via li.ui-menu-item. Why so? :(

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly it works when list of suggestions is loaded but I think the DOM elements in the list are created on the fly hence the need of adding class after the DOM elements actually exists, with just this line of code is hard to tell what's happening

Comment: the same code is working fine for me....check if there is some other issue